# User is able to access other users data using others JWT token via postman tool

Tags: jwt, resteasy, restful-authentication

we have web application with REST web services.User can access those web services using his JWT token. but if he got token of other user is some way then he is able to perform CRUD operations on other data.

so basically how i can restrict other users from doing this and restrict then to access  unauthorized data though user have token of other user?

Comment: The JWT token *is* the authentication. The system relies on only the user having their JWT token and never sharing it, it's like a password in that sense. The JWT access token should be revoked if another person gets hold of a user's JWT token.

Comment: you might want to look into the [OAuth2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) standard if you feel you need another layer of security